# arithmetic calculation with the distance obtained from google API code

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-apps-script

I wrote a java script code to calculate driving distances along the 3 sides of a triangle, corners of which are formed by 3 zip codes. I want to do a simple calculation with the three distances such  as a+b-c and display the result. How should I put the required code in? I tried but I couldn't make it display the calculation result.

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>My Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
     var mapOptions = {
          zoom:      8,
          center:    new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     }
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

     //INITIALIZE GLOBAL VARIABLES
     var zipCodesToLookup1 = new Array('31402', '30308', '30901', '31402');
     var output           = '<tr><th scope="col">From</th><th scope="col">To</th><th scope="col">Miles</th></tr>';
     var difference = "0";
     document.write(difference);
     //EXECUTE THE DISTANCE MATRIX QUERY
     var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
     service.getDistanceMatrix({
          origins:      zipCodesToLookup1,
          destinations: zipCodesToLookup1,
          travelMode:   google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem:   google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
     }, function(response, status) {
          if(status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
               var origins = response.originAddresses;
               var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
               for(var i=0; i < origins.length-1; i++) {
                     var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                     output += '<tr><td>' + origins[i] + '</td><td>' + destinations[i+1] + '</td><td>' + results[i+1].distance.text + '</td></tr>';

               }


               document.getElementById('zip_code_output').innerHTML = '<table cellpadding="5">' + output + '</table>';
          }
     });
}

//FUNCTION TO LOAD THE GOOGLE MAPS API
function loadScript() {
     var script  = document.createElement("script");
     script.type = "text/javascript";
     script.src  = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCDZpAoR25KSkPTRIvI3MZoAg1NL6f0JV0&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
     document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="zip_code_output"></div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:650px; height:600px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if bug or missing code or invalid JS.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  Your currently posted code is not complete (at a minimum it contains a syntax error).

Comment: @geocodezip I have added the complete and tested code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a second property of the [distance](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Distance) .value which is the distance as a number of meters.  Add those up and convert the result to miles.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/290edqug/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  //INITIALIZE GLOBAL VARIABLES
  var zipCodesToLookup1 = new Array('31402', '30308', '30901', '31402');
  var output = '<tr><th scope="col">From</th><th scope="col">To</th><th scope="col">Miles</th></tr>';
  var difference = "0";
  var totalDist = 0;
  //EXECUTE THE DISTANCE MATRIX QUERY
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: zipCodesToLookup1,
    destinations: zipCodesToLookup1,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
      for (var i = 0; i < origins.length - 1; i++) {
        var results = response.rows[i].elements;
        output += '<tr><td>' + origins[i] + '</td><td>' + destinations[i + 1] + '</td><td>' + results[i + 1].distance.text + '</td></tr>';
        totalDist += results[i + 1].distance.value;

      }
      output += '<tr><td></td><td></td><td>' + (totalDist / 1000 * 0.621371).toFixed(2) + ' mi</td></tr>';


      document.getElementById('zip_code_output').innerHTML = '<table cellpadding="5">' + output + '</table>';
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="zip_code_output"></div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: I modified the code with if/else statement to calculate distance a-b-c. The code output is null. Where did I go wrong? Updated code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/290edqug/3)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misread your question and oversimplified but if you're just looking to test your output use:

```
var calculation = distance();
console.log(calculation);
```

If you're looking to display it via HTML use something like

```
var calculation = distance();
document.getElementByID('insertYourIDHere').innerHTML = calculation;
```

Where distance() is your function that calculates the distance

Comment: Could you look at the code again? I have added the complete and tested code above. Thanks in advance!